# How to make scrollbar transparent in React app

Tags: reactjs, scrollbar

I am trying to make the scrollbar (track) to be invisible while only making the thumb visible in React app. However, it is not working (as the scrollbar background becomes white which I assume is the default browser color) even after setting *::-webkit-scrollbar-track* to have:

1. background or background-color: transparent
2. opacity: 0%

Ideally, I want to make the track to be invisible so that it blends in with the background while only showing the thumb.
As of now, the scrollbar is simply set to have gray for the track and dark gray for the thumb. I would greatly appreciate any help.

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Scrollbar */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.5vw;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: #0d111767;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: rgb(99, 99, 99);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
/*------------------------------------------------- */

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

.App {
  background-color: #0D1117;
  color: white;
}

rest of the code...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  background-color: transparent;
```

will work. Issue is the the scrollbar is located in the body and not the app so it is getting the body color. Add your background color to the body instead of to .App and you'll get the desired effect.

Here is a link to an example.
https://codesandbox.io/s/make-scrollbar-transparent-23f4y7?file=/src/styles.css
Uncomment the background-color in body and the scroll-bar-track will be transparent.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like transparent scrollbar (using webkit-scrollbar) is best suited for a website with a single colored background.